# RegExp in Javascript String Split method

Tags: javascript, regex

The following Javascript code snippet is from the famous Javascript book by Nicholas C. Zakas:

```
var colorText = “red,blue,green,yellow”;
var colors1 = colorText.split(“,”); //[“red”, “blue”, “green”, “yellow”]
var colors2 = colorText.split(/[^\,]+/); //[“”, “,”, “,”, “,”, “”]
```

It is quite difficult to understand how the second `split` works.

Can anyone explain it?

Comment: second regex matches any combination of characters except `,` and `\`

Comment: `colorText.split(/[^\,]+/);` does spliting on words, like red yello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript split will based on delimeter what you give. if you give "," it will omit "," from string and give between string characters as an array.

in RegEx case you are choosing expect "," so it's omits other characters and only four "," as an array

Answer (score 0):

```js
function aa(){
var x1 = 'red,blue,green,yellow';
var x2=x1.split(",");
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=x2[0];
}
```

```html
<div id="test" onClick="aa()">
test
</div>
```